# SED Assistance Needed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a script which will modify a line within a file based on a string.  I cannot determine the correct sed syntax if the string contains both spaces and brackets.

Original String:

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
```

Change Needed:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
```

I have written the following and it works; however, because it only mathces a partial string, I'm afraid it could modify other lines within the file unintentionally.  I want to match the entire string to avoid that.

```
#!/bin/bash
File=/etc/sysconfig/iptables
String=":INPUT"
sed -i -e "/$String/ s/DROP/ACCEPT/" $File
```

Comment: Just how much of the original string is considered fixed and suitable for matching? In the extreme case, you can simply match the entire string and replace it: `sed -i -e 's/^:INPUT DROP [0:0]$/:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]/'`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i -r 's/(:INPUT )DROP( \[0:0\])/\1ACCEPT\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to replace all `DROP`s for an iptables chain with `ACCEPT`s, use an anchor for the beginning of the line:

```
String=':INPUT'
sed -i -e 's/^\( *'"$String"' *\)DROP/\1ACCEPT/' "$File"
```

The command captures the `$String` pattern at the beginning of the line (`^`) with a number of optional spaces (`*`) around, and refers to the captured content with `\1`.

If, however, you want to match the entire line, use an anchor for the end of line (`$`) as well:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\( *'"$String"' *\)DROP\( *\[0:0\] *\)$/\1ACCEPT\2/' "$File"
```

You likely want to make the expression slightly more flexible by allowing any number of digits for the `[<packet-counter>:<byte-counter>]` pair, since the counters are of no importance for the logic of the iptables rules:

```
sed -i -e 's/^\( *'"$String"' *\)DROP\( *\[[0-9]\+:[0-9]\+\]\)$/\1ACCEPT\2/' \
  "$File"
```

The command above replaces the entries of a saved iptables file as follows:

```
< :INPUT DROP [0:0]
< :INPUT DROP [618709275:676424577017]
---
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
> :INPUT ACCEPT [618709275:676424577017]
```

Also note the use of double quotes. Enclosing a variable in double quotes prevents reinterpretation of special characters, except `$`, backtick, and `\`. Otherwise, you risk to apply the command to multiple files (if, for instance, `$File` contains a `*`).